Unable to connect to shared printer on Windows 10 from Ubuntu
When connecting to a shared USB printer on a Windows 10 host using Samba in Ubuntu 20.04, it fails with the following error message:
NT_STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED
Can anyone help please?

How is things configured? You include no information...

Connected to Windows Printer via samba from Ubuntu Printer settings. Share name in windows identified and HP laser jet pro M203 drivers installed but the printing failed with the NT STATUS message. In windows enabled smb1, turned on file sharing and turned off password protection. Added smb user and password in Ubuntu same as Ubuntu login.

What about the Windows share permissions and Windows printer permissions?

Given everything though can u Just tell me where to look for

Windows login doesn't have password. Should I create one and turn on the password protection in windows. Further please let me know if Linux and windows user and password has to match

Welcome to the site. When asked for clarifications, please don't respond in comments, but edit your post to include the requested information. Reading through the comments is rather painful, and comments are subject to removal without notice by moderators.
